# Nginx returning 400 for requests with authenticated-SSL

Tags: python, nginx, urllib2

I have a server that expects requests from a Python 2.7.6 client via authenticated-SSL. It's been working for months in production, as well in my local development environment. They both use Nginx. Primarily, I'm developing on a Mac, but for the purposes of identifying this problem, I'm running out of a Ubuntu 14.04 VM.

Starting Friday, the client is getting 400 ("Bad Request"). I have not explicitly upgraded or changed anything. Version-control agrees that nothing has changed. It only breaks when talking to local (not production), so I assume it's an Nginx problem. However, it still works with cURL to local.

This is the 400 content that's returned:

```
vagrant@deploy:/deployment/deploy_scripts/dev$ ./curl_ds_host_shell.py 
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine over cURL:

```
curl -s -v -X GET -k --cert /var/lib/rt_data/ssl/rt.crt.pem --key /var/lib/rt_data/ssl/rt.private_key.pem https://deploy_api.local:8443/auth/admin/1/hosts
```

It also works with Python 3.4 . It seems to only be a problem with urllib2/httplib (I'm using *requests*, which calls urllib2/httplib). This direct example fails:

```
import urllib2
import httplib

cert_filepath = '/var/lib/rt_data/ssl/rt.crt.pem'
key_filepath = '/var/lib/rt_data/ssl/rt.private_key.pem'

url = 'https://deploy_api.local:8443/auth/admin/1/hosts'


class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    """Wrapper to allow for authenticated SSL connections."""

    def __init__(self, key, cert):
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler.__init__(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert

    def https_open(self, req):
        # Rather than pass in a reference to a connection class, we pass in
        # a reference to a function which, for all intents and purposes,
        # will behave as a constructor
        return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)

    def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
        return httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, key_file=self.key, cert_file=self.cert)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler(key_filepath, cert_filepath))
response = opener.open(url)

response_data = response.read()
print(response_data)
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?